Can't grant Cloud Functions Invoker to Firebase Functions
I'm trying to deploy my Firebase Functions to a project which is part of an Organisation under a GSuite account.
The account I'm logged into the firebase CLI and console have Owner IAM permissions.
When I deployed my functions it said:

Unable to set the invoker for the IAM policy on the following functions:
You may not have the roles/functions.admin IAM role

I granted myself that role via the Google Cloud Admin for future new function deploys and went to add the Cloud Functions Invoker role to all the deployed functions.
But I can't add it, it errors with:

Invalid state '': The operation failed with precondition error. This is usually because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution.

What does this even mean and how do I solve it?

If the Firebase CLI isn't working as you'd expect and doesn't give a meaningful error message, you should reach out to Firebase support for assistance.

This is what you're looking for. From here

Go to IAM and admin > IAM (link)
Make sure the organisation is selected in the dropdown at the top (not a project)
For the profile with the “Organisation Administrator”, click on the pencil “Edit principal”
Click on “ADD ANOTHER ROLE”
Search for the the "Organisation Policy Administrator" roles  -- firewall, privacy (necessary to edit policies in the next step), select them
Go to IAM and admin > Organisation policies (link)
Click on “Domain restricted sharing”
Click on “MANAGE POLICY”, leave everything as default and remove any existing rules.
Click “ADD A RULE” and add choose “Allow all”
Finally click “SET POLICY”

Now you should be able to deploy the cloud functions
